# Polynomial $ax^2 + (b+c)x + (d+e)$

Tags: polynomials

Let $a, b, c, d$ be real number such that polynomial $ax^2 + (b+c)x + (d+e)$ has real roots greater than $1$. Prove that polynomial $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ has at least one real root.

Is my work correct ?

Let $r$ be real root of $ax^2+(c+b)x+(e+d)$, so $ar^2+cr+e=(br+d)(-1)$.

Let $P(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$

so $P(\sqrt{r}) = ar^2+cr+e + br\sqrt{r}+d\sqrt{r}= (br+d)(\sqrt{r}-1)$

$P(-\sqrt{r}) = ar^2+cr+e - br\sqrt{r}-d\sqrt{r}= (br+d)(-\sqrt{r}-1)$

Since $\sqrt{r}>1$, so $P(\sqrt{r})>0>P(-\sqrt{r})$

By Intermediate value theorem, $P(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ has at least one real root.

Comment: FWIW:  Is $br + d > 0$?

Comment: Otherwise, your conclusion does not follow.

Comment: It is still true if $br+d<0$, by a totally similar method. If $br+d=0$, you can find that $\sqrt{r}$ is required. @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the roots are $r_1,r_2$. Then:
$$a(x-r_1)^2(x-r_2)^2=ax^2+(-ar_1-ar_2)x+ar_1r_2=0.$$
Hence the second equation:
$$f(x)=ax^4-ar_1x^3-ar_2x^2+(ar_1r_2-e)x+e=0.$$
Note:
$$f(r_1)=-er_1+e$$
$$f(0)=e$$

Now IVT is applicable.

Comment: Thank you, faruhota. Please show me on how to apply IVT.

Comment: Consider two cases: $e>0$ and $e<0$. In each case $f(r_1)$ and $f(0)$ have opposite signs.

Comment: Also remember $r_1>1$. And of course, if $e=0$, then $0$ is the root of $P(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm clear now. Could you please point out the error in my work ?

Comment: if $r>1$ is real, what is $P(\sqrt{-r})$? Isn't it a complex number you are operating with?

Comment: I've edited my work, $P(\sqrt{-r})$ has been changed to $P(-\sqrt{r})$. Is it correct now ?  BTW, why do you have two roots of $r_1$ and two roots of $r_2$ ,e.g., the polynomial may have three roots of $r_1$ and one roots of $r_2$ ?

Comment: Referring to the comments, $P(\sqrt{r})>0$ depends on the sign of $br+d$, like in my solution on $e$. The quadratic equation has two roots $r_1,r_2$ and I am using only one of them, namely $r_1$ snd $0$. For the polynomial $r_2$ is not used, though it could also be used instead of $r_1$.

Comment: Thank you. If $br+d$ is positive, we have $P(\sqrt{r})>0>P(-\sqrt{r})$. And if $br+d$ is negative, we have $P(-\sqrt{r})>0>P(\sqrt{r})$. In either case, we can apply IVT. Am I right ?

Comment: Right. Now it is complete and in a sense advantageous to mine because you handled the problem with one root. Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate for your kind help, farruhota.